# Вывод нуля после запятой TextView

Tags: c#, xamarin, textview

Здравствуйте. Через вот такой метод, элементу TextView присваивается значение.
Переменная rating хранится в double. И при значении 5.3 красиво выводится 5.3, но при значении 1.0 выводится 1 без нуля. Как сделать чтобы этот ноль присутствовал через метод SetText?

RatingTextView.SetText(pRating[e.Position].rating.ToString(), TextView.BufferType.Normal);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй `rating.ToString("0.0#")`. Это выведет значение с как минимум одним знаком после запятой и максимум двумя знаками. Если знаков исходного числа больше, то оно округляется. Таким образом можно задать необходимый формат. `0` отобразится всегда, `#` отобразится, если есть что отображать.

```
Console.WriteLine(1d.ToString("0.0###")); // выведет 1,0
Console.WriteLine(1.23d.ToString("0.0###")); // выведет 1,23
Console.WriteLine(1.2345d.ToString("0.0")); // выведет 1,2
```